# Assign tags correctly to cells and subviews of uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, cell

Hey guys i've been stuck on this problem for 2 days in a row, so i'm asking if there is anybody out there that can give me a hand.

I have a tableview that is made up of 4 sections.

section 1 ->made up of just 1 row where its cell contains a subview which is a uiimageview

section 2 ->made up of 2 normal rows(just 2 plain simple cells with text in them)

section 3 -> made up of 1 normal row

section 4 -> made up of 1 row, where its cell contains a subview which is a uitextview that can contain dynamic text, so the uitextview's height and consequently the cells height varies depending on how much text is in the uitextview.

Here's the code to create this structure:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


//create a nsstring object that we can use as the reuse identifier
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

//check to see if we can reuse a cell from a row that has just rolled off the screen
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//if there re no cells that can be reused, create a new cell
if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:_viewForImageHeader];

            break;

        case 1:
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = 0;
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:16.0];

            break;

        case 2:
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:16.0];
            break;

        default:
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:_textViewForArticle];

            break;

    }

}
else{

    NSLog(@"in else");

}


//here i fill in the 2 normal cells with text


return cell;

}
```

When the uitableview loads(in portrait mode) everything is perfect(image is in section 1, section 2 and 3 contain their correct text and in section 4 i have my dynamic text). But when i start to rotate the app, all the cells get mixed up. For example i find the contents of section3 in section 4 and vice versa.

I think this has to with the fact that i am not maybe reusing the cells correctly. Should i use tags, and if so, how can i implement the use of tags in the specific case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `switch` case outside `if` condition - after the `if and else`

Comment: I'm trying to accept your answer but the system is telling me that i must wait another 3 minutes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because of reusing cells.  You have a few options here, but if you will never have more than the 5 cells in this tableView, by far the easiest and most optimum solution is to not reuse cells.  In other words, instead of calling "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier", just allocate a new cell each time.

When you have many more cells, this would degrade performance, but if your cells are static and limited (as they appear to be), there is no real gain from trying to reuse cells.

If you DID have 4 "types" of cells and more rows (more dynamically allocated cells), the solution would be to subclass UITableViewCell for each of the 4 "types" of cells and then to call the correct one based on the section or whatever your criteria is.

Comment: Thank you so much @HarryStack. So following what you are telling me, if i use user427969's solution i am creating a new cell each time, therefore the cells won't get mixed up. In my project i have used user427969 solution but i realy appreciated your input and i will keep in mind what you have told me for future reference.

Comment: I would love to upvote this answer as well as user427969's one but i don't have 15 rep points :(